# Cuando enciendo el emulador de Android Studio me quedo sin internet

Tags: android, android-studio

Cada vez que enciendo el emulador (ya sea con aplicaciones desarrolladas como sin ellas)(La aplicación es un Hola Mundo). Mi MacBook se queda sin internet a medias.

Cuando me refiero a medias quiero decir que puedo usar el buscador de google en los exploradores (Safari, Chrome, etc) pero luego no puedo acceder a ninguna en pagina externa a google (por ejemplo stackoverflow.com).

En cambio desde el emulador todo funciona correctamente, porque uso el explorador del emulador y puedo acceder a todas las paginas sin problema.

Tengo la ultima version de android studio instalada, de MacBook tengo la version Big Sur.

HE probado a eliminar los emuladores y volver a crearlos, con diferentes ajustes y sistemas operativos pero ya no se que hacer.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: El problema es tu conexión, si tu emulador falla esto no causará que tu internet fallé, recuerda preguntar en base a [ask]., saludos